# Замена по регулярке с учетом регистра

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Допустим есть слово кот (банальный пример), оно может стоять как в начале предложение и начинаться с большой буквы, так и в середине предложения и быть с маленькой буквы и его нужно заменить на собака

Можно ли сделать чего-нибудь хитрое, что бы Кот заменился на Собака, а кот заменился на собака с маленькой буквы?

У меня есть пара идей:

1)Составить по 1 регулярки для каждого случая

2)Анализировать первую букву совпадения

Мб есть какой-нибудь еще интересный вариант?

Comment: Да как то особо больше вариантов и не придумаешь. Возможно, если ваш язык позволяет вызывать callback функции во время замены, эта функция и могла бы проверять регистр.

Comment: @Mike, да, C# позволяет